# Dynamically adding new data to view

Tags: java, android

I'm working on the app which should download some data form server (done) and then show then. Same way as for example android market app (searching) works. It also need to be click-able items. I was thinking about using for example linear layout and somehow dynamically creating new textview's Is this a good way to do this? Can anybody provide some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). This widget displays items in a list fashion, you can customize how each row of the list looks and what data you want to display. Google Market probably uses [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html), since they display apps in rows with several columns.

Here is a [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) on how to use `ListView` (or for [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)). Plus there are tons of related stuff available in SO.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.somelayout);
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("some text");
layout.addView(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling your story like you need a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), which is the view used in the Android market to display apps. You can use this in combination with the setOnItemClickListener method to make them clickable.

On [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-onclick) site, I found this example which would serve your needs.

```
public class ListviewOnclickExample extends Activity {

private ListView lv1;

/*
 * Instead of putting your test here, 
 * load it from the internet in the oncreate method
 */
private String lv_arr[] = { "Android", "iPhone", "BlackBerry",
        "AndroidPeople", "J2ME", "Listview", "ArrayAdapter", "ListItem",
        "Us", "UK", "India" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));
    lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // Do your click stuff here
        }
    });
}
```

}

The XML file is res/layout/layout.simple_list_item_1.xml and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can customize your view so it shows more than just one word, a good tutorial to do this can be found [here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) Google IO video about listviews is certainly worth watching too if you want to know more about them. For the things you describe the above should be enough.